# Im trying to make a math wiz game and I cant get it to work

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random
from time import sleep
import math

print('Hello! What is your name?')
myName = input()
print('Welcome to the math wiz game!')
print('Lets start with the easy stuff!')
print('what is 2*4?')
if input == 8:
    print('Your right!')
```

Where am I going wrong with this code?

Comment: Hi Kai, welcome to StackOverflow. Please see question-posting guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your questions accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your last 2 statements like this:

```
ans1 = int(input('What is 2*4?\n'))
if ans1 == 8: 
    print("You're right!")
else:
    print("Sorry")
```

Answer (score 2):

There was no need for the imports.
Here is the corrected version

```
    print('Hello! What is your name?')
    myName = input()
    print('Welcome to the math wiz game!')
    print('Lets start with the easy stuff!')
    print('what is 2*4?')
    NewVariable = input()
    if a == 8:
        print("Your right!")
    else:
        print("You don't even know this!")
```